# Does an Android Game Center exist?

Tags: android, game-center

I am working on one Android application which needs the gaming center like an 
apple game center . Does Android provide any game center like apple game center?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Center

And if so:

- is it an opensource or paid one?
- What are the limitations of this one as compared to apple game center?
- or what are the feature's of it as compared with apple game center?
- which devices supports game center of android?

I am working on one application in which i want to share my application with more than one user at a time at a same time. (say multi player game).  Apple game store provides facility for multiplayer game i want this kind of facility in android.

Comment: You don't need more then 1 `?` after each question. Also: provide us with some details of what you need and why you need it. There are bound to be people that know enough of Android to help you, but have no clue what an "apple game center" is supposed to do.

Comment: @Nanne i had edited my question. please go through it actually i want to use multiplayer facility for my game..

Comment: Do you want social **leaderbord** funcionality, or do you want multiplayer **matchmaking**, and if so, to what degree?

Comment: in simple way i can tell you is there is one game which is developed in android and i want to play that game with more than one user's at a time... (not individual) all together is it ok?? i think apple provides this facility inn apple game center (i am not sure as i had not used). thanks

Comment: Android has launched it's own equivalent to the Game Center last year: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games&hl=en

Answer (score 6):

In case you want a ready-made leaderboard solution, you could take a look at <strike>[OpenFeint](http://www.openfeint.com) and similar solutions.</strike> **Update 2/6 2013:** Since OpenFeint being discontinued, I'd recommend its successor [GREE](https://developer.gree.net/en/). They have shared leaderboards between Android and iPhone too. It's not open source, but it's free. You should look at their [support site](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/welcome/) for limitations. [This](http://www.iphonenuts.com/game-center-v-openfeint) post looks at OpenFeint compared to Game Center.

Comment: OpenFeint is now gone :(

Comment: Tried GREE. It has mixed Chineese-English content user experiance. I doubt it is user friendly. But, of course, you can recommend your game to friends.